# customizing individual enumerate keys

Tags: lists, enumerate

I want to customize (say underline) individual enumerate keys. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item OK

\begin{enumerate}

\item Should be $\rm(\underline a).$

\item OK

\end{enumerate}

\item Should be $\underline 2.$

\item OK

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't use `\rm` and it's not necessary to switch to math mode for `\underline`

Comment: If such an \item is followed by \label, the counter in the \ref does not seem to increase properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update the counter in question manually in two ways:

1. Stepping it, either with `\stepcounter` or `\refstepcounter` if you want proper referencing capability;
2. Setting the appropriate format as the optional argument to `\item[..]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item OK
  \begin{enumerate}
    \refstepcounter{enumii}% \stepcounter{enumii}
    \item[(\underline{\theenumii})] Should be (\underline{a}).
    \item OK
  \end{enumerate}
  \refstepcounter{enumi}% \stepcounter{enumi}
  \item[\underline{\theenumi}.] Should be \underline{2}.
  \item OK
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The first level of `enumerate` has counter `enumi`, the second level has `enumii`, ...

Comment: Maybe it's better to use `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter`, because the latter doesn't work with `\label`-`\ref` system.

Comment: @skevin93: Done.

Answer (score 2):

The changing of individual keys is 'difficult', by design, since this breaks the consistent typesetting!

However, it's possible by using the optional argument to the `\item` macro.

Using `\item[\underline{\theenumi}]` (\theenumi outputs the counter value of the first enumeration level) is not sufficient, since at this time of typesetting the counter isn't stepped. Using `\refstepcounter` before is possible. I decided to show another way, with `\numexpr`.

Some notes:

- Don't use `\rm` -- it's deprecated in LaTeX
- It's not necessary to switch to math mode for `\underline`

---

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item OK

\begin{enumerate}
\refstepcounter{enumii}
\item[\underline{(\theenumii)}] Should be \underline{(\theenumii)}.


\item OK

\end{enumerate}

\item[\underline{\the\numexpr\number\value{enumi}+1}.\refstepcounter{enumi}] Should be \underline{2}. and is \underline{2}. now!
\refstepcounter{enumi}
\item[\underline{enumi}.] Does work also
\item OK

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]